# What is the actual index of table array in HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

When we add integer as a key in `HashMap` , the default hashcode() is the value of the integer and we know hashcode corresponds to bucket which is the index of table array where Entry objects are placed .So if the integer is 1000 , size of array will be 1000 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, typically the array of hash buckets starts out small (16 in the current implementation), and will be expanded as the number of entries in the table increases beyond the "loading factor".  At each expansion the size of the array is doubled.  The actual hashtable index is calculated as `hashCode % numberOfBuckets` so the hash code value is "collapsed" to fit in the current table size.

I suggest you go look at the [source code on grepcode.com](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap)

Note that resizing the hash bucket array is a very expensive operation, as all hash indexes need to be recalculated and all entries reinserted into the new data structure, so it pays to guess the necessary size in advance if at all possible.